# PHP Option Group

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Option Group that I built with PHP.  All was fine until I had to get the value of DetailID instead of DetailName to lookup records.  I still need the DetailName to display but not the DetailID, I need to add the DetailID to this.  How would I do that?

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$sql = "SELECT DetailType AS type, DetailID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DetailName
          ORDER BY DetailName ASC   
          SEPARATOR '|') AS DetailName FROM tblDetails GROUP BY DetailType"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo "<optgroup label='{$row['type']}'>"; 
    $DetailNames = explode('|', $row['DetailName']); 
    foreach($DetailNames as $DetailName) { 
        echo '<option value='.$DetailID.'>'.$DetailName.'</option>';
    } 
    echo "</optgroup>";
}  
?>
```

Tables.
tblLocDet
LocationID   1,1,2,3
DetailID     1,2,3,4

tblDetails
DetailType   Feature, Meal Period, Service, Type
DetailID     1,2,3,4
DetailName   Buffet, Fireplace, WiFi, Waterfront

Comment: Why.  This doesn't help.

Comment: can you show an example of your table data?  I'm guessing DetailID goes with DetailName, so when you group by DetailType, all your DetailID's get grouped into 1.

Comment: Yes Marc.  This creates an Option Group of which there are 4.  This is all working correctly.  I just need to add DetailID to the first row so that I can pull records based on that.  I am getting records now based on DetailName.  But I need to still have DetailName show in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who down voted.  If it was such a lame question, you could have answered it!  It's easy to be negative.

Comment: Turkeys. Absolute Turkeys. Nothing constructive.  You are all wrong.  The problem is you didn't take a minute to comprehend what was being asked.

Answer (score 2):

This works......

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT DetailType AS type, DetailID, DetailName FROM tblDetails
            ORDER BY DetailType, DetailName";
                     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                     $prev='';
                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                     if ($prev != $row['type']) {
                         if ($prev) echo "</optgroup>";
                         echo "<optgroup label='{$row['type']}'>";
                         $prev = $row['type'];
                         }
                         echo "<option value='".$row['DetailID']."'>".$row['DetailName']."</option>";                            }
                         echo "</optgroup>";
```